# how to create a xml with multiple same tags with python

Tags: python

how to create a xml with multiple same tags with python
the xml is like this i want multiple tag(param) under the root node(DOCUMENT):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <DOCUMENT content_method="full">
        <param key="k1" value="0001"/>
        <param key="k2" value="0002"/>
        <param key="k3" value="0003"/>

    </DOCUMENT>
```

here is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from xml.dom.minidom import Document

doc = Document()  
DOCUMENT = doc.createElement('DOCUMENT')
DOCUMENT.setAttribute('content_method',"full")
#DOCUMENT.setAttribute('xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation','DOCUMENT.xsd')
doc.appendChild(DOCUMENT)

param= doc.createElement('param')
param.setAttribute('key',"k1")
param.setAttribute('value',"0001")

DOCUMENT.appendChild(param)

f = open('/home/tel.xml','w')
#f.write(doc.toprettyxml(indent = '\t', newl = '\n', encoding = 'utf-8'))
doc.writexml(f,indent = '\t',newl = '\n', addindent = '\t',encoding='utf-8')
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the problem by just creating the param object in 3 times as below

```
for i in range(3):
    param= doc.createElement('param')
    param.setAttribute('key',f"k{i+1}")
    param.setAttribute('value',f"000{i+1}")
    DOCUMENT.appendChild(param)
```

You can write elements again which has the same tag.